# How to get the tweets of the all the users who have tweeted for particular twitter handle?

Tags: python, rest, twitter, tweepy, data-analysis

I have scrapped the tweets of a particular twitter handle and it has returned all the recent tweets with the username of the people who have tweeted. Now I want to know what were the tweets of the users for that particular twitter handle

Comment: post some code so we can help

Comment: new_tweets = api.user_timeline(screen_name=screen_name, count=200)

Comment: see the problem is I have all the usernames who have posted for a particular twitter handle. This was returned by the user_timeline method , now I want to know what were the tweets of the people for that particular twitter handle